# download a canvas as an image in chrome extension

Tags: javascript, html, canvas, google-chrome-extension

This code work for me for downloading a canvas as an image in a custom html page:

```
var save = function() {
            var x= document.getElementById("output-canvas");
            var dt = x.toDataURL('image/png');
            this.href = dt;
};
downloadLink.addEventListener('click', save, false);
```

but it doesn't work (without any errors) for canvas in popup.html in a chrome plugin which i am developing.

Could anybody help me with a solution for downloading canvas items in a chrome plugin?

Edited:

This is my manifest file:

```
{
  ...
  "permissions": [ "contextMenus", "tabs", "http://*/*", "https://*/*", "activeTab", "storage"],
  ...
}
```

Comment: What's your manifest.json's "permissions" value? Do you put any image elements into the canvas?

Comment: @wOxxOm I've edit my question and add manifest info. Your next question answer is positive if i well understood.

Comment: Hmm, permissions seem okay assuming the original image has a http:// or https:// URL. Just in case, did you look at the [popup's console](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38920982/)? (it's in the different place)

Comment: @wOxxOm yeah it has. yeah both console seems clear. Also I can't see 'Save image as ...' when right click on the canvas. which may have relation with this problem. Any idea?

Comment: I guess your link element does not have a `download` attribute.

Comment: yes @wOxxOm. thanks for your help. it fixed my issue: 
downloadLink.download = "download";

Comment: @MajidMobini Did you publish that plugin? care to share the link?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Checklist:

1. The image URLs you draw on canvas should be allowed in manifest.json ["permissions"](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/declare_permissions):

   ```
   "permissions": [
     "activeTab",
     "https://i.imgur.com/*"
   ],
   ```
2. The link element should have a [`download` attribute](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/HTML/Element/a) that contains a name of the file to save:

   ```
   <a download="test.png" href="...">Save me</a>
   ```

   or

   ```
   var link = document.createElement('a');
   link.download = 'test.png';
   link.href = canvas.toDataURL('image/png');
   document.body.appendChild(link);
   ```